# Kindle's sleep mode: keeping last page on screen

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite

Since it is E-ink, is there a way to keep the last page read on screen instead of screensaver/ad?

(And if not, why not? it is a killer feature...)

Answer (score 1):

You're right, there is no reason for it not being *technically* possible.  In other words, you can do that if the firmware lets you do that. Which, AFAIK, the native Kindle firmware does not. That leaves you with either a hack or jailbreak as your options, if you're feeling adventurous: I found a [relevant thread on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kindle/comments/5nb284/anyway_to_disable_screensaver_for_paperwhite_2015/) that could point you in the right direction. (Also, I have been educated it's called "off screen" not "screensaver", as it's not saving anything. Which... I don't agree with, see below.)

As for "why doesn't Kindle allow this", that's an interesting question.

I would theorize that it's for the same reason we used screensavers on CRT monitors: replacing a page of text with a picture helps to avoid ghosting/residual image and therefore extend the life of the screen.

I mean, aside from the obvious, which is "we gotta put the ads *somewhere*" ;)

Comment: No, burn-in (ghosting) does not occur on e-ink displays. That's exactly why it's not a screen saver as there's nothing to 'save'. If an e-ink display was susceptible to burn-in then the off-screen image itself would be a problem. Screen savers on CRT monitors *moved*.